# Laravel's HTTP Basic Authentication works locally, but not on remote server

Tags: laravel, basic-authentication

I have a blog where I've created a simple admin section. I decided to use Laravel's implementation of basic authentication since I would be the only one needing access. This works fine for me locally, but when I push my code to the server it's not allowing me to authenticate.

To troubleshoot this, I first ssh into my server and try the following steps:

1. run `php artisan key:generate`
2. run `php artisan tinker`
3. `$user = new User;`
4. `$user->email = 'name@email.com';`
5. `$user->username = 'name@email.com';`
6. `$user->password = Hash::make('1234');`
7. `$user->save();`
8. Confirm the database entry looks right: `4|name@email.com|name@email.com|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|2014-09-25 14:07:20|2014-09-25 14:07:20`
9. Try authentication

I have FastCGI enabled, so added the additional requirements for my .htaccess file per Laravel's documentation:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # HTTP Authentication if FastCGI is enabled
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive on
      ExpiresByType text/css                "access plus 2 hours"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript  "access plus 2 hours"
      ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 2 hours"
      ExpiresByType font/truetype           "access plus 2 hours"
      ExpiresByType font/opentype           "access plus 2 hours"
      ExpiresByType image/png               "access plus 2 hours"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

However, it's still not working. Any suggestions I can try to debug this?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this myself and realized I was editing the wrong .htaccess - the one in the root folder. Edit the .htaccess in your public/-folder and you should be good to go.

Comment: @tarazed84 I ended up just using the standard authentication.The .htaccess file I'm using is in my public directory. I'm also using it to cache my resources (css, scripts and images), so I've been able to verify its working.